# Can we develop silverlight application using Visual Studio TeamFoundationServer express edition 2012

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a requirement for developing a Silverlight application and I have visual studio TFS 2012 express edition already installed in my system.
Can I use this vs tfs for my purpose?
If not what all softwares / tools / ides I need to have installed in my system.

Please help..

Comment: What's your purpose exactly? If it is only to develop a Silverlight application ... why should TFS as a source control not work?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend against starting a new project using Silverlight right now. Silverlight, Flash, and other similar technologies are largely being supplanted by HTML5.

Comment: Silverlight is a dead technology. Microsoft have designated Silverlight, WCF, and a few other technologies as 'feature complete'. This is code for 'no future investments'

Comment: I think you are mixing up product name.  TFS and VS are two different things, TFS has nothing to do with Silverlight, VS on the other hand does.  Now VS 2012 Express if this is the product you have installed does support Silverlight application. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537667(v=vs.110).aspx